# Blank screen in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, graphics-card, event-log

Recently I bought new computer (AMD FX-6300, 8GB RAM, SSD and GTX650 as graphic card). I installed Windows 8.1. At the beginning everything went well. But after one day I have two strange problems.

1) From time to time screen is blank for 1-2 sec. After first time it happens more often, to moment when monitors (I have two) are black, then I have to reset Windows, go into SaveMode and disable graphic card driver. Restart. I enable again graphic card and I can use computer for one day, to moment when this happened again.

I have installed the freshest graph drivers and Windows updates, I check my computer with antivirus (AVG), by CHDSK, SFC etc but they don't found any errors. I found something interesting in EventLog, I think it could be a reason, but I cannot find any useful information about this error.

```
The desktop window manager has encountered a fatal error (0x8898009b)
```

2) Time and date is changing without any reason. I turn off sync with time.windows.com. What else could change date in my computer, how can I profile it?

My main question is how to solve: "The desktop window manager has encountered a fatal error (0x8898009b)" error

Thanks for all your hints and suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find solution of my problem.
There is source: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/the-desktop-window-manager-has-encountered-a-fatal/ae44c9ea-3b52-451d-a371-91ae375ce353?page=2)

1. Run cmd as Administrator.

   Type bcdedit /set useplatformclock true <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Type bcdedit /enum <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Verify that useplatformclock is on/true.

   Restart the computer.

Answer (score 2):

1) You'll have to do some troubleshooting regarding your graphics card (and different versions of its drivers). I'm not sure anyone can give you one specific answer, as this most likely requires many steps in order to narrow down the exact issues. But, I would start with downloading the newest GPU drivers for the GTX, and maybe one a few versions old, and seeing if one or the other solves the issues.

2) Having a dead CMOS battery in your motherboard can cause the time on your machine to be incorrect when it boots or wakes up. A CMOS battery is cheap, and is very easy to replace on Desktops.

Since this new PC possibly has a dead CMOS battery, and you're having other hardware issues, it could be that your machine is in some way defective. It was were bought as a PC-in-a-box, rather than assembled yourself, then you may want to just exchange the machine for another one at the store you purchased it from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) I had the newest version of Nvidia drivers.  Do you have any idea where can I find more details about my error, I think it is key to resolve my problem.It's good idea with change battery.

Comment: This is the latest driver for your card, which came out 4 days ago: http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/79527 Because it's so new it could very well be buggy and be causing you issues. That's why I also suggested downloading an older version, such as: http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/78873 which wasn't released *this* month.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but my problem exists with older driver version

Comment: Is this a desktop PC? If so, do have have onboard graphics you can try hooking your monitors up to, instead? If the problem persists with the integrated graphics, we can probably rule out your GTX as the issue. If it goes away, then it means further troubleshooting of the GTX is necessary.

Comment: It is desktop, but I don't have integrated graphic card, only external. I use two monitors: Acer H213H (DVI) and Lg Flatron L1752S (VGA port)

Answer (score 0):

From some research I saw that other people with this problem uninstalled a certain Windows Update and the error didn't appeared anymore.

The update in question is Platform Update for Windows 7 x64-Edition (KB2670838). Try to uninstall this update and see if this fixed your problem.

I'm not saying that this will certainly work for you but it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: I can not fin this update (KB2670838). I have Windows 8.1

Comment: This update is a prerequisite update for IE10. Try to see if you have the update for IE10 in Windows Updates and uninstall it. It should uninstall also this prerequisite.

Comment: It may be part of a cumulative update, rather than one that was downloaded individually.